# Rails Signup form doesn't create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i Have a submit form which doesn't create upon clicking the submit button.

this is the form

```
   <%= form_with model: @user, url: sign_up_path do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :Email %>
   <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    
   <%= f.label :password %>
   <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    
   <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    
   <%= f.submit 'Sign Up', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>      
<% end %>
```

the controller

```
def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Successfully created account'
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

the route

```
  get 'sign_up', to: 'registrations#new'
  post 'sign_up', to: 'registrations#create'
```

i have checked the logs and this is what its displayed

```
Started POST "/sign_up" for ::1 at 2021-02-24 13:37:53 +0000
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"2h2OVVFYBAfIZfBcsNDlZZ5/e4q4MN/ar+6WudUFq7o0e+vWGaRBdytAEDJis2vTbXa6+Eng91DhFbKqenmdPw==", "user"=>{"email"=>"apaa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
  Rendering registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.4ms | Allocations: 909)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
```

what could possibly be the problem
Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 92)
Rendered shared/_flash.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 21)
Completed 200 OK in 329ms (Views: 48.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 6702)

Comment: Failed validations, most likely. Replace `save` with `save!` and you'll see

Comment: yes it was the validation. i've fixed it thank you